# Java get information about WebSphere by programmatic way

Tags: java

I need to get information about installed profiles WebSphere and WebSphere version. I use the desktop Java applications. The information you need to get by programmatic way, without using .bat
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WASDirectory API to get the installed product version if you know the location of the installation.  For example, if you have installed WebSphere Application Server Base V8.5 in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer,

```
import com.ibm.websphere.product.WASDirectory;
public class WASInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WASDirectory was = new WASDirectory("/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer");

        System.out.println(was.getVersion(WASDirectory.ID_BASE));
    }
}
```